# Hide browser bar in mobile version

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, viewport

I am trying to hide the browser in mobile version and have tried to use below on load:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // This hides the address bar:
        window.scrollTo(0, 5);
    }, 0);
});
</script>
```

However this isn't working on my android device it is only scrolling down 5px and not hiding browser bar as if human scrolled down. I feel like this has something to do with viewport but can't figure.

I have tried to follow https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/ as well but I can only it make it work with click. I don't really want to go full screen really just hide browser as if user has scrolled down on load (if scrolled up than visible again).

I found a site that has something similar (https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/internet/interstitial-ads-google-hate/amp/) - this happens when you enter via link google search and before entry into site the browser bar has already been hidden, ie scrolled down to google search.

If anyone can help point to right direction that would be helpful so I canget started to code the script that I need. Ideal android and ios resolution (if not than just android)